# Why colon sintax error

Tags: python-3.x

I'am new to all this so I am sorry if it is a very obvious mistake.
I'm trying to write a code to determine whether X is dividable by Y without a remainder, but I constantly get a "Syntax Error" on the colon after the "IF" statement.

```
x = int(input('Number to test: '))
y = int(input('Number to divide by: ')
if x%y==0:
        print('Divisible')
else:
        print('Undivisable')
```

Thank you in advance.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: `int(input('Number to divide by: ')` is missing closing bracket for `int()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a closing parentheses (`)`) on the second line. This should work:

```
x = int(input('Number to test: '))
y = int(input('Number to divide by: '))
if x%y==0:
    print('Divisible')
else:
    print('Undivisable')
```